# Bash error: "b.sh: line 52: syntax error: unexpected end of file logout"

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, scp, eof

So, I wanted this to download a file from my computer, transfer it to my iPhone, install the file there, and respring my phone. For some reason the error you saw in the title pops up. Would be nice if someone could help, thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
cd downloads
if [ ! -d ".tmpdl" ]; then
  mkdir ".tmpdl"
fi
cd .tmpdl
echo "Enter .deb link:"
read dllink
echo "Enter name of tweak (simple):"
read name
echo "Enter IP of device:"
read IP
echo "Enter your SSH password. If you don't know what this is enter 'alpine' without the apostrophes."
read pass
echo "Sending test file..."
touch test.txt
sshpass -p "$pass" scp test.txt root@"$IP":/var/mobile/Documents
echo "If the transfer was successful (no permission denied error) enter yes or no if it wasn't."
read reply1
if [ $reply1 == no ]; then
 echo "Error, wrong credentials, try again."
 exit
fi
echo "Okay, attempting to download file..."
curl -o "$name".deb "$dllink"
if [ ! -d "tmp" ]; then
  sshpass -p "$pass" ssh root@"$IP" << EOF
   cd /
   cd var/mobile/Documents
   mkdir tmp
 EOF
fi

sshpass -p "$pass" scp "$name".deb root@192.168.1.104:/var/mobile/Documents/tmp
echo "Sent file, deleting it from here..."
cd ..
rm -rf .tmpdl
sshpass -p "$pass" ssh root@"$IP" << EOF
  cd /
  cd var/mobile/Documents
  mkdir tmp
  mv "$name".deb tmp/
  cd tmp
  dpkg -i "$name".deb
  echo "Clearing caches..."
  cd ..
  rm -rf tmp
  echo "Done installing, respringing now..."
  killall backboardd
EOF
```

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines:

```
if [ ! -d "tmp" ]; then
  sshpass -p "$pass" ssh root@"$IP" << EOF
   cd /
   cd var/mobile/Documents
   mkdir tmp
 EOF
fi
```

have the problem.  The EOF is not at the beginning of the line (indented by one space), so it is not the end of the here-doc, and hence the here-doc is not terminated until the end of the file (where there happens to be a second EOF that's supposed to be terminating a second here-doc), and that generates the error message because the `if` is not terminated with a `fi`.  Unindent EOF and you should be in business.